# $\mathbb{E}[Z \, Z^T] = I$ with $Z$ gaussian standard vector and $I$ identity matrix

Tags: probability, expected-value, gaussian

I'm wondering why $\mathbb{E}[Z \, Z^T] = I$ with $Z$ gaussian standard vector and $I$ identity matrix.

If I expand the expectation, I get:

$$
\mathbb{E}[Z \, Z^T] = \mathbb{E} [Z_1^2 + \quad \ldots \quad + Z_d^2]
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Z=(z_1,z_2,...,z_d)$ is s.t. $z_k\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1),k\leq d$ IID then
$$ZZ'=\begin{bmatrix}
z_1^2&z_1z_2&...&z_1z_d\\
z_1z_2&z_2^2&...&z_2z_d\\
...&...&...&...\\
z_1z_d&z_2z_d&...&z_d^2
\end{bmatrix}$$
[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable#Correlation_and_cross-correlation)
$$\implies E[ZZ']=\begin{bmatrix}
E[z_1^2]&E[z_1z_2]&...&E[z_1z_d]\\
E[z_1z_2]&E[z_2^2]&...&E[z_2z_d]\\
...&...&...&...\\
E[z_1z_d]&E[z_2z_d]&...&E[z_d^2]
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&...&0\\
0&1&...&0\\
...&...&...&...\\
0&0&...&1
\end{bmatrix}=I_d$$

Comment: Hello @Snoop perfect expanation!

Comment: why $\mathbb{E}[z_1^2] = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[z_1 \, z_2]=0$? Can you write this two terms explicitly  in your answer please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi as the variables have mean zero, $E[Z_1^2]$ is the variance of $Z_1$ and $E[Z_1Z_2]$ is the covariance btw $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. By definition they are respectively $1$ (for all $Z_k$) and $0$ (for all pairs)